# Referencing defined symbols when simplifying equations

Tags: simplifying-expressions, replacement

*Question*: How can I tell Mathematica to replace a sub-expression (in a simplified expression) with a symbol if the symbol is defined to be that sub-expression?

Say you have defined:

```
f[x_, y_] := some_complicated_expr_using_x_and_y_1
g[x_, y_] := some_complicated_expr_using_x_and_y_2
h := some_complicated_expr_using_f_and_g
```

then you do `D[h,x] // Simplify`, you would get an expression that has sub-expressions `some_complicated_expr_using_x_and_y_1` and `some_complicated_expr_using_x_and_y_2`.

How can I tell Mathematica to replace `some_complicated_expr_using_x_and_y_1` with `f[x,y]`?

For a concrete example, consider:

```
h[μ_, r_] := Sum[x[μ, s]*w[s, r], {s, 1, n}]
yhat[μ_, r_] := σ[h[μ, r]]
e := (1/(2 m)) Sum[Sum[(y[μ, r] - yhat[μ, r])^2, {r, 1, p}], {μ, 1, m}]
h[μ, r]
yhat[μ, r]
e
D[e, w[i, j]]
```

I you evaluate the above you will get

[image: mse]

How can I get it to produce:

[image]

(which equals to `Out[97]`)

I have tried `ReplaceRepeated` but got no luck:

[image]

Comment: to get halfway there you need to have the unevaluated forms of the expressions on the rhs of `ruleh` and `ruleyhat`. That  is,  use `HoldForm[h[μ, r]] ` and `HoldForm[yhat[μ, r]]`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the result of the operation `D[e, w[i, j]]`:

```
Clear[yhat];
expr=(1/(2 m) (\!\(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(\[Mu] = 1\), \(m\)]\(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(r = 1\), \(p\)]\((\(-2\)\ \((
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(s = 1\), \(n\)]\*
TemplateBox[{RowBox[{"i", ",", "s"}]},
"KroneckerDeltaSeq"]\ \*
TemplateBox[{RowBox[{"j", ",", "r"}]},
"KroneckerDeltaSeq"]\ x[\[Mu], s])\)\ y[\[Mu], r]\ \*
SuperscriptBox["\[Sigma]", "\[Prime]",
MultilineFunction->None][
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(s = 1\), \(n\)]w[s, r]\ x[\[Mu], 
              s]] + 2\ \((
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(s = 1\), \(n\)]\*
TemplateBox[{RowBox[{"i", ",", "s"}]},
"KroneckerDeltaSeq"]\ \*
TemplateBox[{RowBox[{"j", ",", "r"}]},
"KroneckerDeltaSeq"]\ x[\[Mu], s])\)\ \[Sigma][
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(s = 1\), \(n\)]w[s, r]\ x[\[Mu], 
              s]]\ \*
SuperscriptBox["\[Sigma]", "\[Prime]",
MultilineFunction->None][
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(s = 1\), \(n\)]w[s, r]\ x[\[Mu], 
              s]])\)\)\))) /. \[Sigma][a_] -> yhat[\[Mu], r] /. 
 Derivative[1][\[Sigma]][a_] -> yhat'[\[Mu], r]
```

Try this:

```
expr /. \[Sigma][a_] -> yhat[\[Mu], r] /.Derivative[1][\[Sigma]][a_] -> yhat'[\[Mu], r]
```

yielding thew following:

[image]

Have fun!